# 500 Internal Server Error on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to install a themeforest theme on localhost, where I have wordpress.

Once I try to create one by zip, it does 500 Internal Server Error.
So I take the folder and copied within the `themes` folder. It works, I've activate it, with the needed plugin.

But when I try to import some content, it does the same: http://localhost/WPWebSite/wp-admin/admin.php?import=wordpress&step=1&_wpnonce=e9592e8da9
Is there some problem with localhost and connecting outside?

I follow this for debug: https://snapcreek.com/blog/wordpress-error-log-friend/ :

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

but I can't see any log file after repeating the operation.

Also, I've set:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

What can I also do? I can't understand where the error is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you're trying to upload a file that exceeds the maximum of your web server.

Open your `php.ini` and make sure your `upload_max_filesize` can handle the size of your file.

Then change your Apache vhost settings to add the following directive:

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 2000000
```

Once both has been done, restart your Apache and try importing again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well i was also facing this error on one of my server and everything was fine.
In last i after loads of debugging i noticed that permission was not appropriate.
Make sure you don't have 777 permission
PS i am assuming you are using a linux system
You may also check your local server's log. 
If you dont know where to find logs use `<?php phpinfo() ?>` this will show you the path of log files.
All the best

Comment: I see. It was `mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 137536 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen`. Why I can display that error on the web page?

Comment: maybe your php.ini settings have turned off the error reporting so its not showing the error message

Comment: How can I enable them? I've E_ALL

Comment: Check the error_reporting, display_errors and display_startup_errors settings in your php.ini file
after making changes restart apache

Comment: Yeah they are all ON :(